# Can I use ninject to change implementations on the fly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject

Using ninject, I know I can bind to a certain implementation, such that whenver I do:

```
ISomeCache myCache = Ninject.Get<ISomeCache>();
```

It will load my concrete implementation that I binding ninject to.

Say I store which concrete implementation I want to use in the database (web application), and when I change that in the admin panel it should on the fly use the class I want.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

As long as you can determine the context in which you are executing, yes you can do it.

```
kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyUserService>().When(request => GetSiteContext() == "user");

kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyAdminService>().When(request => GetSiteContext() == "admin");
```

where GetSiteContext is a method you would write to determine what context you are executing in. `.When(...)` takes a `Func<IRequest,bool>` as a parameter (equal to `Predicate<IRequest>`).